# PyCharm giving error while setting up interpreter: no such option: --python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm

I am trying to create a project in Pycharm and I am getting this error when I use **New Environment Using** **Pipenv**, I do think there is no **--python** options in Pip3, so how do I bypass this in PyCharm and set up my project

[image]
[image]

Comment: Pip is not an interpreter. Can you show us what the previous screen looked like?

Comment: It looks like you chose pip in the path for pipenv. Pip != pipenv.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile it was auto-generated by PyCharm, may I know which location I have to select for PipEnv ?

Comment: Had you read the pipenv docs? Jetbrains even has a page on setting up [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pipenv.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipenv is different from pip, and you'd have to install Pipenv separately, then point Pycharm at it

https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv

How to setup pipenv in Pycharm is documented here

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pipenv.html

Otherwise, you should chose an option other than Pipenv

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense, then I have to install pipenv seperately, thanks for the link
and yes currently other options are working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

`pip` is package-management system for python.
I think what you looking for is to set up a new interpreter/venv

That can be achieved by hitting that button highlighted in the photo

[image]

Comment: But I am getting the error whem im setting up new venv, when i select conda it works fine, so how I set up PIP with my conda environment ?

Comment: each virtual environment has an individual pip, there's nothing to be set up

Comment: thanks for that detail, got some idea on how pip and virtual environment work now

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you give the wrong " pipenv.exe " address to pycharm as pipenv executer like the following snapshot.

To create a pipenv interpreter, first you need to install pipenv with following command :

```
pip install pipenv
```

then make sure your computer knows where to look for the executer files of pipenv which is the Scripts folder in python directory of your device

if you have pipenv there you are all set.

go to pycharm > settings > interpreter settings , click show more from frop down menu, click plus to add new interpreter and finally choose "pipenv"

**IMPORTANT** :

- **set base interpreter to python.exe file from python directory**
- **set pipenv executable to pipenv.exe file from python directory/Scripts**

you are all set to use your pipenv interpreter now :)

**quick check list**

1. make sure you add the python folder and also Scripts folder to the path on your system
2. make sure you are pointing to pipenv.exe file instead of other files in Scripts folder

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHrtO.png)